# URL date access missing

Tags: bibtex, url

I am using a Mendeley bibtex file in my LaTex document and my citations include journal articles and websites. When I compile my document, the bibliography entry for the website does not show the 'URL date accessed'. Can you advise on how I can include this please?

I attach my bibtex code, bibliography file and pdf output. I am using Texworks (version 0.6.2) downloaded from MikTex (version 2.9)

LaTex doc.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}
Test 1
\cite{Nature2017}

\bibliography{library}
\end{document}
```

[image: PDF output]

Bibtex

```
@misc{Nature2017,
howpublished = {https://www.nature.com/nature/},
title = {{Nature}},
url = {https://www.nature.com/nature/},
urldate = {02/12/17}
}
```

I can't seem to find a solution online so any help you can give will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `plain` bibliography style has been around, more or less unchanged, since the mid-1980s. Unsurprisingly, then, it wasn't programmed to process fields called `url` and `urldate`. (What's being picked up in your formatted bib entry is the field `howpublished`.) You should be using a more recent bibliography style, say, `plainnat` (and load the `natbib` bibliography style).

Comment: Are you maybe required to use the `plain` bibliography style? Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

The `plain` bibliography style is one of the "orginal" BibTeX bibliography styles, and it's been around more or less unchanged since the mid-1980s. As such, it wasn't set up to do anything with fields called `url` and `urldate`, in no small part because the Internet didn't even exist yet and acronyms such as URL were but an idea in Tim Berners-Lee's mind. Do consider using a more modern bibliography style, i.e., one that at least recognizes the field `url`.

Assuming that, for some reason, you're stuck with having to use the `plain` bibliography style, I suggest you transfer the contents of both the `url` and `urldate` fields to a field called `notes` (and lose the `howpublished` field, since it just repeats the URL-related information). And, be sure to load the `url` and/or `hyperref` packages in order to activate the `\url` macro.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{library.bib}
@misc{Nature2017,
title = {Nature},
note  = {\url{https://www.nature.com/nature/}, last accessed on 02/12/17},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}

\begin{document}
\cite{Nature2017}
\bibliography{library}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Mico. I'm quite new to LaTex and using it for the first time so I haven't looked around for a better style yet. Are you able to suggest a good style for thesis writing? If I were to keep using 'plain', do I need to have my citation details in the same .tex document?

Comment: @Kevin - Your real bib entries should *always* be in a file with extension .bib. (The `filecontents` route shown above, which created a file called `library.bib` "on the fly", was used just to make the code self-contained.) Not knowing what your university's (or department's) formatting guidelines are, I really can't make a meaningful, let alone authoritative, recommendation. It really depends on your college or university.

Answer (score 2):

Use package `biblatex` and program `biber` which make more sense:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{library.bib}
@online{Nature2017,
    editor = {Philip Campbell},
    publisher={Macmillan Publishers Ltd.},
    title = {Nature},
    location={Great Britain},
    url = {https://www.nature.com/nature/},
    urldate = {2017-12-02},
}   
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}
\begin{document}
    Test 1
    \cite{Nature2017}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Herbert. I tried your suggestion but I can't get the same result. I am using Mendeley which only produces a bibtex file. Does biblatex and biber work with Mendeley?

Comment: Mendeley should be able to export a correct BibTeX file. See http://www.bar54.de/2014/02/mendeley-and-latex-bibtex/: 2. Biber

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who struggles with this, some more explanation:

It works with mendely without making much alterations in the bibtex file, as many suggested. LaTex reads "urldate" as Year-Month-Day. So this the the entry format in mendely using "date accessed".

In the case above:
In mendely, enter at "date accessed" : 2017-12-02

Or directly change it in the Bibtex file:
urldate = {02/12/17} should be: (in european format): urldate = {2017-12-02}

This will show up in the reference list as (visisted on 02/12/2017)

Hope this helps!

https://www.mendeley.com/guides/web-citation-guide

Comment: I suppose you should write "mendeley" instead of "mendely". I don't know if it is true, so I don't edit your answer. Anyways, welcome to TeX.SE.